# JPA Criteria - Can I modulus on extracted month number from database date?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, modulo

I have some problem with JPA Criteria, I need to do modulus on extracted month from date in database. It is possible? I use PostgreSQL. Below is my code:

```
Expression<Integer> monthExpression = cb.function("month", Integer.class, root.get(Contract_.billingPeriodStartDate));
        qbp.setRestriction(cb.or(
                    cb.and(cb.equal(root.get(Contract_.billingPeriod), BillingPeriod.Annually),
                            cb.equal(monthExpression, month)),
                    cb.and(cb.equal(root.get(Contract_.billingPeriod), BillingPeriod.SemiAnnually),
                            cb.equal(cb.mod(monthExpression, 6), month % 6)),
                    cb.and(cb.equal(root.get(Contract_.billingPeriod), BillingPeriod.Quarterly),
                            cb.equal(cb.mod(monthExpression, 4), month % 4)),
                    cb.equal(root.get(Contract_.billingPeriod), BillingPeriod.Monthly)
                )
        );
```

My error:

> mod(double precision, integer) doesn't exist

Comment: Works on Integer https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#mod(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the value `Expression<Integer> monthExpression = cb.function("month", Double.class, root.get(Contract_.billingPeriodStartDate)).as(Integer.class);`